# Magento 2.1 braintree credit card error handling

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

In Magento 2, I am using brain-tree credit card payment method on live site. Sometimes it shows error,
unable to place an order, please try after sometimes
but I want to know exact error on front end side about that transaction declined. I want error handling for Braintree credit card payment so that it makes easy to know the reason behind failed payment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Magento 2 use Ajax to handle this task. 
[image]

We should take a look at file:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/place-order.js**

```
      return storage.post(
            serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(payload)
        ).fail(
            function (response) {
                errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
                fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            }
        );
```

So, we need to override this file or the `errorProcessor.process()` - `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/error-processor.js` handler. We can alert the error message.